# How can I disable the trace in rake tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm not sure when this started, but whenever I run a rake task in Rails:

```
$ rake routes
```

Before it prints the routes, it shows the trace:

```
** Invoke routes (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute routes
```

I thought those invoke/execute statements would only appear if I added `--trace` to my command, but it happens for all of my rake tasks (db create/migrate, Capistrano, etc.)

Is there a way to disable the trace functionality? Is there a configuration file in Rails that might be enabling trace that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been tracked down to a custom gem that implements a Capistrano Plugin. The gem allows for a different version control system to be used with Capistrano other than the ones they provide (Git, SVN, etc.).

The ultimate issue was that `capistrano/lib/capistrano/all.rb` has this line:

```
Rake.application.options.trace = true
```

This file was being loaded with the Capistrano Plugins, but the default ones are not required until used in the `Capfile`. When we created a custom gem with a new plugin, we simply added the new gem to our application's `Gemfile`, which loads the files by default. So our plugin file looked like this:

```
# custom_gem/lib/capistrano/scm/custom_vc.rb
require 'capistrano/scm/plugin'
class Capistrano::SCM::CustomVC < Capistarno::SCM::Plugin
  # ... Mimic the capistrano/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb in the Capistrano gem.
end
```

The top line that requires `capistrano/scm/plugin` was ultimately requiring the `capistrano-lib/capistrano/all.rb` that was setting trace to be on for all Rake tasks.

**The solution was to simply add `require: false` to our Gemfile for the custom gem.**

```
# Gemfile
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano_custom_vc', require: false
end
```